# Angular ui-grid: Additional Menu Button

Tags: angular-ui-grid

Is it possible to add a second button directly below the menu button in ui-grid? I'd like to add a button with a custom function (to hide/show filters). I have a button that works, but I want it inside of the grid header row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it using `position: absolute` to put the button in the top-left corner. You can do the same to put the icon in every **fixed** position, like under the menu button.
The html is something like this:

```html
<div style="position: relative">
    <!-- ui-grid -->
    <div ui-grid="options" ui-grid-selection></div>
    <!-- filter button -->
    <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;">
        <a href="#" ng-click="toggleFilters()"><!-- filter icon --></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

My result:
[image: screenshot]